# Table Status Management - Dynamic Fields

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I plan on tables to manage the status of all from a single center field.

I created two table;

First table name is "EntityGroups" (Sample Data : "Members","Baskets","Products")

Second table name is "EntityStatusTypes" and this table related with first table. 1 - N

Finally, I put "EntityStatusID" all tables.. have the following diagram.

How accurate do you think of this ? Is there a performance issue ? All status field has been dynamic but i afraid performance problems...!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i solved this design problem. I removed all relations from tables. So i load all entity status when application init. I think this way is better than others (for perfomance and extensibility)